# couchbase-cli: command not found

Tags: couchbase, ubuntu-18.04

I downloaded deb package from https://www.couchbase.com/downloads and installed it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i couchbaseXXX.deb
```

It is **successfully** installed but when I try to execute:

```
couchbase-cli bucket-create -c localhost:8091 -u Administrator ****
```

Returns:

```
couchbase-cli: command not found
```

What is the issue behind that, How to fix it?

Comment: It seems like couchbase-cli isn't in the 'path' (or whatever the equivalent is in Linux). Per the docs, couchbase-cli should be somewhere in `/opt/couchbase/bin`. Is it there? https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/cli/cli-intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to setup the couchbase cluster with same command before the bucket creation. An example below, --services could be index,data,query.

/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-cli cluster-init -c 127.0.0.1:8091  -u Administrator -p Public123 --cluster-username=Administrator --cluster-password=Public123 --cluster-port=8091 --cluster-ramsize=49971 --cluster-index-ramsize=2000 --services=data

Answer (score 2):

you have to go into CLI directory location and run the command.
Below are the steps I have done.

```
cd /opt/couchbase/bin

./couchbase-cli bucket-create -c localhost:8091 -u Administrator -p password  --bucket test-data --bucket-type couchbase --bucket-ramsize 100
```

Once I run the above command, I got the success message and the bucket has been created.